# TCP_MAXSEG inaccurate? (Was: Linux path MTU probing not working on accept():ed socket if requested using setsockopt())

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, mtu

Question update: In addition to the problem below, it seems our client/server application using the Linux PLPMTUD mechanism gets too large path MTU. Has anyone seen this, i.e. actual path MTU being 1500, but `getsockopt()` w `TCP_MAXSEG` returning the MTU:s of the endpoints, in our case 3000? I have tried turning of GRO, GSO and TSO with ethtool but the error persists. Normal ping only manages to push through packets 1472 bytes or smaller. Also worth mentioning is that PLPMTUD works perfectly for smaller MTU:s. For example, w endpoints at 1500 MTU and one interface of the intermediate router set to e.g 1200 MTU, the kernel TCP probes and reports correct `TCP_MAXSEG` (1200 - headers).

I am using the Linux RFC4821-compliant packetization layer path MTU discovery in an application. Basically, the client does a setsockopt on a TCP socket:

```
setsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, IP_MTU_DISCOVER, &sopt, sizeof(sopt));
```

with option value set to `IP_PMTUDISC_PROBE`. The `setsockopt()` does not return an error.

The client sends large tcp packets to a discard server, and the path MTU is calibrated by Linux kernel - tcpdump shows tcp packets with DF bit set being sent, packet size varies until the kernel knows the path MTU. However, to get this to work in the other direction (listening server accept:ing connections from clients, sending data and calibrating PMTU in direction from server to client) I have to set the global option for tcp path mtu discovery, `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_mtu_probing`. If I do not, server will stupidly continue to send too large packets, which get discarded by an intermediate router without ICMP sent back. Both endpoints have an MTU set to 3000, while the intermediate hops have MTU 1500.

I hope someone has an idea on what goes wrong. If more info is needed, let me know and I edit the question. Problems exist on both Linux kernel 4.2.0 and 3.19.0, both are stock Kubuntu LTS kernels. (x86/x86-64)

I do set the same socket option server-side as well, on all accept:ed sockets, before sending data in reverse direction.

Comment: Try setting the socket option on the listening  socket instead of the accepted sockets. It will be inherited by them. Setting it on the accepted sockets  may be too late, as the connect handshake has already happened, window scale negotiated, etc.

Comment: @EJP: Good idea, but I tried that earlier without success.

Comment: It sounds like you have an intermediate router that breaks proper path MTU discovery and so, not surprisingly, path MTU discovery doesn't work unless you enable workarounds. What is the mystery exactly? Fix the intermediate router by complaining to whoever administers it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No, Linux has a built in mechanism for PLPMTUD that works even if no ICMP works. (there are some system-wide and socket-specific settings that affect when PLPMTUD is done) And my test network is well-controlled, so for example, i can turn ICMP on and off as I please, and of course also selectively filter out specific ICMP messages. The Linux kernel code was written by John Heffner, and the general concept is in RFC 4821.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I have found workarounds/solutions for the problems, will do more testing but shortly describe my findings here, in case it helps someone else.

The problem with not being able to set path mtu discovery per socket was fixed, brute force, by enabling it system-wide during execution of my program, then disabling again.

The second problem, of incorrect path mtu returned by getsockopt TCP_MAXSEG, was fixed by waiting for TCP ACK of sent TCP data, also using getsockopt (tcp_info.tcpi_unacked). That way, I can be sure that probing has finished before I get TCP_MAXSEG.

Finally, there was a patchset for improving path mtu probing accuracy merged to mainline Linux kernel in March 2015. Without those patches, the probing is very imprecise. Patchset is part of 4.1.y-series kernels and onward.